# Optimize Word Generator

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to build a program capable of finding the best word in a scrabble game. In the following code, I am trying to create a list of all the possible words given a set of 7 characters.

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('dictionary.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)


def FindLegalWords(data):
    LegalWords = []
    for i in data:
        if len(i[0]) <= 15:
            LegalWords.append(i[0])
    return LegalWords


PossibleWords = []


def word_generator(chars, start_with, min_len, max_len):
    for i in range(min_len - 1, max_len):
        for s in itertools.product(chars, repeat=i):
            yield start_with + ''.join(s)


for word in word_generator('abcdefg', '', 2, 15):
    if word in FindLegalWords(data):
        PossibleWords.append(word)
```

I think it is clear that the aforementioned code will take days to find all the possible words. What would be a better approach to the problem? Personally, I thought of making each word a number and use NumPy to manipulate them because I have heard that NumPy is very quick. Would this solve the problem? Or it would not be enough? I will be happy to answer any questions that will arise about my code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: @trincot Data is a list of all the words. I created with the following code with open('dictionary.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

Comment: can't be `FindLegalWords(data)` done once for all before the loop instead of doing it at EACH iteration ?

Comment: Well, it's probably faster to choose suitable words from your existing list of all legal words than it is to generate every possible letter combination and then discard most of them ...

Comment: Anyway, in general: optimizing a bad algorithm (using NumPy to generate letter combinations you're going to discard anyway) is usually worse (and more effort) than choosing a better algorithm in the first place. For example, if you always have a starting sequence, building a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from your set of legal words might be a good start.

Comment: You should consider (strongly) using sets, which are much faster for matching types of things.  Forgetting duplicates (for now), if you made a set of your letters and then grouped all of the words by the set of letters they are comprised of and looked for word groups that were subset of your letters, you're gonna be *almost* there.

Comment: How many data is there in `dictionary.csv` ? Because as you iterate on EACH word, at EACH word generated it's huge? save `xx = set(FindLegalWords(data))` beffore the loop, then do `if word in xx` and tell us if has fasten the whole thing

Comment: From what I remember about Scrabble rules, your code may be incorrect. For example, if your 'hand' in the game is 'abcdefg', then you can't form a word with duplicates like 'add', which needs two d's. So you're probably looking for the equivalent of `itertools.combinations()`, not `itertools.product()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is about 5_539 billion possibilities and codes working with strings are generally pretty slow (partially due to Unicode and allocations). This is huge. Generating a massive amount of data to filter most of them is not efficient. This **algorithmic problem** cannot be fixed using optimized libraries like Numpy. One solution to solve this problem is to directly generate a much smaller subset of all possible values that still fit to `FindLegalWords`. I guess you probably do not want to generate words likes "bfddgfbgfgd". Thus, you can generate pronounceable words by concatenating 2 pronounceable word parts. Doing this is a bit tricky though. A much better solution is to **retrieve the possible words from an existing dictionary**. You can find such list online. There are also some dictionary of pronounceable words that can be retrieved from free passwords databases. AFAIK, some tools like *John-the-Ripper* can generate such list of word you can store in a text file and then read it from your Python program. Note that since the list can be huge, it is better to compress the file and read directly the file from a compressed source.

**Some notes regarding the update:**

Since `FindLegalWords(data)` is a constant, you can store it so not to recompute it over and over. You can even compute `set(FindLegalWords(data))` so to search `word` faster in the result. Still, the number of possibility is the main problem so it will not be enough.

`PossibleWords` will contain all possible subsets of all strings in `FindLegalWords(data)`. Thus, you can generate it directly from `data` rather than using a bruteforce approach combined with a check. This should be several order of magnitude faster is `data` is small. Otherwise, the main problem will be that `PossibleWords` will be so big that your RAM will certainly not big enough to contain it anyway...